# How to populate two input fields (item name, quantity ) from a dropdownlist selection in asp.net core 2.0 razor view

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a list of items with attributes itemname, quantity and price in item table. I would like to populate name and quantity after selecting a dropdownlist in the create order page. I an able to populate item name but the available quantity is not populating in the razor view totalqty input field

The item name is populated but the available quantity is not.

**Controller Section**

```
 public IActionResult Create(string masterid, string id)
        {
            var check = _context.Deliverydetails.SingleOrDefault(m => 
    m.customerInvoiceLineId == id);
            var selected = _context.Delivery.SingleOrDefault(m => 
    m.customerInvoiceId == masterid);
            ViewData["customerInvoiceId"] = new SelectList(_context.Delivery, 
    "customerInvoiceId", "invoiceNumber");
            ViewData["itemId"] = new SelectList(_context.Item, "itemId", 
    "itemName");
            ViewData["ShipmentStatusId"] = new 
    SelectList(_context.ShipmentStatus, "ShipmentStatusId", 
    "ShipmentStatusName");
            if (check == null)
            {
                Deliverydetails objline = new Deliverydetails();
                objline.delivery = selected;
                objline.customerInvoiceId = masterid;
                return View(objline);
            }
            else
            {
                return View(check);
            }
        }


      public JsonResult GetItemDetails(string ItemNo)
        {
            var ItemQuery = _context.Item.Where(x => x.itemId == ItemNo);
            return Json(ItemQuery);
        }

     **Create Order View**


      <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="itemId" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="itemId" class="form-control select2" 
      asp-items="ViewBag.itemId"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="TotalQty" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="TotalQty" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="TotalQty" class="text-danger"> 
       </span>
                </div>
            </div>

Javascript section
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#itemId").change(function (val) {
            var Itemdata = $(this).val();
            $.post('/DeliveryDetails/GetItemDetails', { ItemNo: Itemdata }).then(function (res) {
                console.log("response is", res);  //res is always empty
                $("#AvailableQty").val(res[0].Quantity);

            })
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: "res is always empty " means that the return of the GetItemDetails method has no value .Put the breakpoint at the GetItemDetails method to check the value of the ItemQuery .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following changes in the GetItemDetails method and the javascript

If you want to get the quantity of the item as per the itemId , you could query like below:

```
var ItemQuery = _context.Item.Where(x => x.itemId == ItemNo).Select(x=>x.TotalQty);
```

And in the callback of the $.post() , if you want to populate the totalqty input field , you should add the `id` of the input and set the totalqty  value like below

```
 <input id="totalQty" asp-for="TotalQty" class="form-control" />

 $.post('/DeliveryDetails/GetItemDetails', { ItemNo: Itemdata }).then(function (res) {
                console.log("response is", res); 
                $("#result").val(res);

            })
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add the `[FromBody]` attribute to your controller action. This is because in ASP.NET Core, you need to elect *where* you read your model-binding data from

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetItemDetails([FromBody] string ItemNo)
{
    var ItemQuery = _context.Item.Where(x => x.itemId == ItemNo);
    return Json(ItemQuery);
}
```

I would also be explicit about `[HttpPost]` here as well just to ensure a consistent API surface, unless you want to expose that action through `GET` as well as `POST` by default?

Comment: The OP is posting as `x-www-form-urlencoded`, not JSON. As such, `[FromBody]` is incorrect here, though `[HttpPost]` is definitely required, as it will only respond to GET requests otherwise (the default).